# Install Ubuntu in UEFI mode with Live USB read only in Legacy mode

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, uefi, xps

The machine in question: Dell XPS 2-in-1 9575

Setting Secure Boot off, SSD to AHCI and keeping boot mode to UEFI, the Ubuntu live usb doesn't show up when pressing F12 (boot options) upon boot. Enabling legacy boot options is only available for external devices but that makes it show up.

Installing Ubuntu, in the partitioning screen at the bottom it doesn't say select partition to install GRUB, instead it said to install bootloader which I saw weird. After installing Ubuntu, no matter what combination of Secure Boot, SATA operation (which I'm sure must be AHCI for Ubuntu), boot mode, Ubuntu doesn't show up upon pressing F12 when booting.

On the other hand, using the same BIOS settings and USB drive I was able to setup Ubuntu on an XPS 15 7590 and boot successfully.

I thought burning the Ubuntu Live image on an internal partition and installing from that on to other partitions  should launch in UEFI mode, might solve the problem but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: I had similar problems. I needed to create the life usb drive in UEFI mode, because you can't install a UEFI system when running on a legacy one.

Comment: @choroba Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you wrote, but OP says that they tried to install in UEFI mode and the drive didn't show up in boot menu.

Comment: Is there an EFI directory on the USB drive? Does a file called `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` exist?

Comment: If the USB drive doesn't boot in UEFI, it needs to be updated.

Comment: It looks like in Rufus you need to select gpt & UEFI, not MBR & CSM(UEFI). CSM is really BIOS boot mode of UEFI. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off.  So make sure you have an UEFI bootable flash drive. Ubuntu's standard ISO is configured for both UEFI & BIOS boot, but then may depend on how ISO is extracted onto flash drive.

Comment: The flash drive installed a UEFI copy on my other laptop but the 9575 (the one that it refuses to install on) cannot boot the same flash drive in UEFI mode, it can only booy it in Legacy mode.

Comment: This laptop doesn't boot legacy mode on internal devices.